# Trigger lambda function on CreateSecret event on secrets manager

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-secrets-manager

I have one lambda function which I want to trigger only when secrets managers is created or updated. I am trying to create a eventbridge rule to trigger lambda on any operations on secrets manager. But eventbridge rule is also not triggering. I don't have any cloudtrail trail created explicitly but I can see the logs of secrets manager operations in the event history of cloudtrail

I tried creating a rule using below event pattern

```
{
"source": ["aws.secretsmanager"],
"detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
"detail": {
    "eventSource": ["secretsmanager.amazonaws.com"],
    "eventName": ["CreateSecret", "PutSecretValue", "UpdateSecret"],
 }
}
```

Comment: Were you able to configure this rule (with invalid JSON)?

Comment: Actually, the problem was not with the JSON(typo). I was able to do this by creating a separate trail in Cloudtrail

Answer (score 1):

While recreating a rule using your pattern I realized that the JSON is invalid. Try this one, it works for me:

```json
{
  "source": ["aws.secretsmanager"],
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["secretsmanager.amazonaws.com"],
    "eventName": ["CreateSecret", "PutSecretValue", "UpdateSecret"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, the problem was not with the JSON(typo mistake). I was able to do this by creating a separate trail in Cloudtrail